# Sort text in shell using last word before specific delimiter

Tags: shell, sorting, text, formatting

How do I sort a text file alphabetically in shell using the last word before a certain delimiter as key?

E.g. the following file:

```
Manfred1 Mustermann1 (Berlin)
Manfred Siegfried Müller (Aachen)
Gerd A. Meier (Stuttgart)
```

In this case the delimiter would be " (" and I would like to sort using the last name of the persons in the list. The number of words before the last name is varying.

Given a line of text I know how to extract the key:

```
s="Manfred1 Mustermann1 (Berlin)"
w=${s%% (*}
l=${w##* }
echo $l
```

This displays "Mustermann1", but I did not get any further.

**EDIT**
Using l0b0's answer, this is the complete code that did it:

```
while read s; do
w=${s%% (*}
l=${w##* }
printf "%s\t%s\n" "$l" "$s"
done <names.txt | sort -k 1 | cut  -f 2 > names_sorted.txt
```

where names.txt contains the text and the sorted list will be printed to names_sorted.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've got the sort key (`$l`) you can proceed like this:

1. Print the sort key followed by a tab character followed by the original line, as in `printf %s\t%s\n`.
2. Use `sort`'s `--key` option to sort by the first column (tab should be the default key separator).
3. Remove the sort key and tab character by using `awk` or `grep`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I updated my question and posted the complete solution, but I feel like doing it with a while loop is not really the best way. Any suggestion to that?

Comment: Yes, `while` loops are quite slow. If you need to process lots of lines you should look into combining line processing tools like `sed`, `awk` and `grep` to modify the line as necessary.